# How to know if SD-slot is USB or actual SD-standard?

Tags: usb, ssd, sd-card

I am trying to figure out if my full size or micro size SD card slots on my Toshiba Click Mini 9l has the internals of using USB for SD card slots or if they are wired as actual SD-slots and not useable for resoldering etc (to potentially use it for SSD conversion to use for faster system memory if I can Jam it in).

How can I know this from command line or sparky/tools etc? Thanks.

**Background:**

USB internal bus systems are often used for laptop internals rather than the 1.3V to 3.3V systems for actual SD-card slots, so you can potentially re-use SD-slots if they are simply "USB devices", potentially, maybe. That's what I am getting at.

If you are not receiving a USB-port for these devices then they are not likely to be USB, therefore not able to simply have the SD-card connectors removed/desoldered and a USB to SD-card converter installed etc. Or I may be entirely wrong. This device uses eMMC slower memory and is permanently installed so would like to use an SSD if possible (also a decent thing to know).

Comment: "if they are wired as actual sd-slot" Um, what do you mean with that? this makes no sense to me. Something that read an SD card is an  "actual" SD card reader, and its slot hence an "actual" SD card slot. What do you mean with "wired": Wired to what? How?

Comment: and how would you imagine "unsoldering" anything from a highly dense electronic device? This all makes no sense.

Comment: If `lsblk` sees the card as `/dev/sdx` (where x is the device letter a,b,c ...) it is connected via USB. Otherwise it is connected via PCI and seen as `/dev/mmcblkn` (where n is a number 0,1,2 ...)

Comment: @sudodus thanks, this answers it, is mmcblk3p1 so not useable, nevermind. Put as answered etc.

Comment: To 'put as answered', please click the tick icon at my formal answer below to 'accept my answer'.

Answer (score 0):

If `lsblk` sees a memory card as `/dev/sdx` (where x is the device letter a,b,c ...) it is connected via USB.

Otherwise it is connected via PCI and seen as `/dev/mmcblkn` (where n is a number 0,1,2 ...).

---

Your result `mmcblk3p1` means the *fourth card* (after 0,1,2), 'partition 1' (*first*, maybe only, *partition*). A card reader with several slots may see a card in a certain slot as the fourth card even if it is the only card connected.